# Wordpress Toggle Collapse Speed (Avada Theme)

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, toggle

I don’t know why the toggle is collapsing and closing very quickly. It’s not staying open. This is weird because I've been using this widget to all my websites with Avada theme. Is there something that I need to setup or put on code? Can anyone help me?

http://flexpacio.com/faq/

Jules

Comment: Might be a conflict between plugins or between plugins and the theme that you're using. Try disabling all plugins one by one and see if it works for you. If it doesn't try switching to another theme and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you so much. I deactivated Elementor. And it's causing the issue.